# Convert Long Form data to three dimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, reshape, plyr

I have some data that looks like this:

```
> ExampleData
# A tibble: 14,833 x 4
   CountryCode  Flow      FuelType     Value
   <fct>        <fct>     <fct>        <dbl>
 1 ALB          road      coa            0   
 2 ALB          services  coa            3.3
 3 ALB          manufact  coa          113.1  
 4 ALB          mining    coa            0  
 5 ALB          road      nga            0   
 6 ALB          services  nga            2.4
[...]
```

The data is complete in the sense that each combination of country, flow and fuel type is represented.

I would like to convert this into a three dimensional array where country represents one dimension, flow another dimension and fuel type a third dimension. So I can reference the data X[a,b,c] where a b and c are the respective integer values of my factors CountryCode, Flow and FuelType.

So what I'm looking for is a multidimensional form of 'wide' data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `xtabs` from `base R`

```
out <- xtabs(Value ~ CountryCode + Flow + FuelType, data = ExampleData)
out
#, , FuelType = coa

#           Flow
#CountryCode manufact mining  road services
#        ALB    113.1    0.0   0.0      3.3

#, , FuelType = nga

#           Flow
#CountryCode manufact mining  road services
#        ALB      0.0    0.0   0.0      2.4
```

We can extract individual elements either with position index or the keys

```
out["ALB", "manufact", "coa"]
#[1] 113.1
```

---

Or with `tapply`

```
tapply(ExampleData[['Value']], ExampleData[-4], FUN = I)
```

#### data

```
ExampleData <- structure(list(CountryCode = c("ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", 
"ALB"), Flow = c("road", "services", "manufact", "mining", "road", 
"services"), FuelType = c("coa", "coa", "coa", "coa", "nga", 
"nga"), Value = c(0, 3.3, 113.1, 0, 0, 2.4)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Never heard of xtabs! Super helpful!